# Flask in showing 404 Error in Existing Routes

Tags: python, flask, web, url-routing

I am facing a very weird Issue, In my Flask App when index route (https://sitename.com/) is called everything is fine, but as i navigate to a route like https://sitename.com/about it shows 404 Error, even when About route is created in main.py . This App works all perfect in localhost:5000 but when I deployed it too a VPS It is showing that Error of showing 404 on every route

My main.py

```
from os import environ
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
import requests
import json
import datetime

def getUserData(route):
    if request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For"):
        ip = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")[0]
    else:
        ip = request.remote_addr
    with open("users.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"Page Visited: {route}\n")
        f.write(f"User Agent: {request.headers.get('User-Agent')}\n")
        f.write(f"Remote Addr: {ip}\n")
        f.write(f"DateTime: {datetime.datetime.now()}\n")
        f.write(f"\n\n\n")


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

# Website
@app.route('/')
def index():
    getUserData("Index Page")
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/gallery')
def gallery():
    getUserData("Gallery")
    return render_template('pages/gallery.html')

@app.route('/faqs')
def faqs():
    getUserData("FAQs")
    return render_template('pages/faqs.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    getUserData("About")
    return render_template('pages/about.html')

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    getUserData("Contact")
    return render_template('pages/contact.html')

    
# 404 Handling
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    getUserData("404 Page")
    return render_template("pages/404.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Does it show your custom 404 template?

Comment: @EdoAkse  Yeah, It show the 404 template

Comment: are you sure you are not going to https:/sitename.com/about/ - see that there is a trailing backslash. The way your flask routes are written, navigating to a link with a trailing backslash will return a 404

Comment: You should run the app using app.run(host="0.0.0.0")

Comment: @NoCommandLine https://truvision.semikolan.co/ This is my Route which is Totally working fine, but as i go to https://truvision.semikolan.co/faqs It is showing the 404 Error.
It is quite strange thing that at only /about there is 502 Bad Gateway Error and other routes have 404 Error

Comment: I am getting 502 Bad gateway error for both your home page and /faq

Comment: @NoCommandLine Because to resolve this Issue I just messed up with my Nginx Configuration